# Deploy Azure Web App using .NET Core Application

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, gitlab, azure-web-app-service

We are using Gitlab as a Source code management and we created a Web application, need to deploy code from GitLab to Azure Web app.

Plan to use ARM Template/anyone script that will help us to run the script through a .NET core application. Any suggestions/code samples/ any reference doc?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: any sample scripts to deploy web app(Source: .NET Application available in GitLab) in Azure?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to do the deployment task via C# as opposed to using Git integration in App Services or something similar? https://christianliebel.com/2016/05/auto-deploying-to-azure-app-services-from-gitlab/

Comment: Yes, looking for a deployment task. Deployment task is in Bash script needs to run from c# console app.